# What is the actual definition of "polarizing form", in the context of cohomology algebras?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry, algebras

I am studying Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry*, in order to better understand the underpinnings of her 2008 paper on Hodge structures.

She discusses elements $\omega$ in $H^{2}(X; \mathbf{R})$ that "polarize" the cohomology algebra $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbf{R})$ when $X$ is compact and Kaehler.  She lists some properties of this "polarizing form/class", including the fact that the Lefschetz decomposition of the algebra is orthogonal with respect to the intersection form on $H^{k}(X;\mathbf{R})$ given by cupping $\omega^{n-k}$ with a pair of $k$-classes.

So far, though, I don't see an explicit definition for "polarizing form/class".  Is this merely alternative terminology for the de Rham cohomology class of a Kaehler form?  There is nothing to indicate that the properties she lists *are*, explicitly, the defining qualities of a "polarizing class".  They just seem to be "useful things to know" about the class.

I would like to see if this polarizing concept can be extended to non-Kaehler forms, but first I need to understand it in the Kaehler case.  Help, please?